Why does an accelerated clock record fewer events?
A clock is set up to continuously broadcast its indicated time via radio waves to non accelerating observers in different inertial frames of reference. The clock also continuously records its readings so that at the end of the experiment there is a single record upon which all observers will agree on the patterns of acceleration during the experiment.
The clock is accelerated and its tick rate is observed to decrease by all observers relative to the tick rates of their local clocks. Note that the tick rate in such an experiment could also increase but in this specific experiment it is found to have decreased. The clock's indicated time is lagging progressively behind the times indicated on the clocks of the observers as illustrated by series of numbers representative of clock readings below:

At the end of the experiment all observers will agree that the continuous record of indicated times recorded by the clock during the experiment indicates that subsequent to the acceleration less events were recorded by the clock.
This is a real non-reversible observer-independent effect. Less events are recorded by the clock subsequent to acceleration.
Is the accelerated clock recording less events than the observer clocks due to time literally flowing at a reduced rate in its frame of reference or is there a physical explanation at the level of quantum events for this observation?
To my knowledge there is no evidence for the material existence of a time medium that physically flows at different rates. The definition of time in Physics is simply "that which is measured by clocks" which I take to mean a quantity of events (e.g. Caesium atoms changing between 2 states) observed to be simultaneous with another quantity of events (e.g. a train passing between all the points on a station platform).
Einstein seems to take the same view stating "If we wish to describe the motion of a material point, we give the values of its co-ordinates as functions of the time. Now we must bear carefully in mind that a mathematical description of this kind has no physical meaning unless we are quite clear as to what we understand by “time.” We have to take into account that all our judgments in which time plays a part are always judgments of simultaneous events.".
What really is causing this actual reduction in the frequency of atomic transitions? Even if we consider that in the accelerated frame time flows more slowly there still has to be a physical explanation as to what causes time to flow more slowly and how the reduced flow of time interacts with quantum particles to reduce the quantity of quantum events.

The answer is that time dilation occurs more on relatively-fast moving clocks. Are you asking what the physical mechanism behind time dilation is?

Time dilation is a popular phrase that characterises the observation but offers no explanation as to what it is that causes a change in the frequency of events recorded by a clock that is accelerated. Even if time is a physical medium that flows at variable rates there must be a physical explanation for how it influences quantum events.

The reason time dilation occurs is because your four-velocity in any frame of reference must equal $c$, that is if you consider the rate at which you're moving through space and the rate at which you're moving through time to be a single 4-vector, the norm of the vector is always $c$. When stationary, your vector points entirely in the "time direction". When you begin to move, it angles away from that direction so that the vector has nonzero spatial components. As a consequence the time component of the vector is reduced, hence apparent time dilation. Marco Ocram's answer is the correct one.

What do you mean by the "time direction"? Time is not an observable thing and therefore cannot have a direction. All that we can observe are events that we characterise as representing a passage of time. What do you mean by stationary?

In 3+1-dimensional spacetime, it makes sense. You could also try constructing a stationary observer watching a moving clock in Minkowski spacetime yourself; in such a spacetime, time is considered to be a coordinate, and what I said makes sense.

@jamesfairclear What do you mean by "material evidence"? What "physical explanation" are you looking for? Relativity is a model of the universe in which spacetime is modeled as a 4D manifold. It is one of the most accurately experimentally verified theories so far. The purpose of physics is to create accurate models of observed reality rather than fundamentally answer why the universe is the way it is.

Vincent Thacker. Time is not generally considered to to be a real physical medium. In physics it is defined simply as a measurement taken from a clock. There is no evidence for the material existence of a time medium that affects the progress of clocks. What we observe is that an accelerated clock records a different quantity of events than a clock that is not accelerated. The physical explanation for this could be that time literally slows down or, if time is not a real medium, perhaps a reduction in the frequency of quantum events related to the increased distance travelled through space.

"time is considered to be a coordinate". In my experience nobody working in the field of Physics considers time to be anything more than a reading taken from a clock. A coordinate is strictly a set of numbers relating to a point in space. We can characterise time as a coordinate but in the final analysis it can only ever refer to a reading from a clock. And clocks are notoriously unreliable when accelerated. Spacetime is a convenient mathematical framework for predicting the path of an object in a gravitational field but it is not a real physical medium.

@jamesfairclear said “ its tick rate is observed to decrease by all observers relative to the tick rates of their local clocks”. This is incorrect in general. In some frames the acceleration will increase the speed, in others it will decrease the speed. The tick rate will decrease or increase accordingly

The first false statement from your original post is the one I quoted in my answer below.  Now that you"ve edited, the first false statement is in line 1, where you characterize this feedback as "nonspecific".

@WillO the non specific feedback was from PeterDonis outside of this thread! However if you separately feel that I have posted false information in this thread please provide details and substantiation of your claim.

Observer A has a piece of paper with tick marks on it.   Observer B has a piece of paper with tick marks on it.  How is comparing these pieces of paper going to tell anybody anything about the speed at which those marks were created?

@WillO "A has a piece of paper with tick marks on it. Observer B has a piece of paper with tick marks on it. How is comparing these pieces of paper going to tell anybody anything about the speed at which those marks were created?".
There is just one record of the continuously recorded indicated times from the clock during the experiment shared with all non accelerating observers. As an illustration the numbers recorded might look something like 0,15,30,45,60,70,78,84,88,90. From this we can discern that the clock was accelerated after 60 and consequently recorded fewer events after that.

@SolomonSlow For example an atomic clock records each Caesium transition event that causes it to progress. In a light clock it is the event of light striking the mirror. The set of recorded events are unique to the clock's mechanism and, from the distribution of events during the experiment, reveal to any non accelerating observer, without necessarily referencing another clock,  that fewer events are recorded after acceleration. An observer comparing side by side his own clock with the readings broadcast from the other clock will see the accelerated clock recording progressively fewer events.

Re, "The clock also continuously records its readings..." Can you explain what you mean by that? It almost sounds as if you are saying that, at the start, it records the number zero, Fifteen seconds later, it records the number 15. Fifteen seconds after that, it records the number 30, and so on. But what could be the purpose? We already know in advance the exact sequence of numbers that it will record. How can we learn anything by reading that record after the fact?

@jamesfairclear, I still don't see the point of having the clock keep a record of its own internal state unless it also records external events that appear to happen simultaneously (in the clock's own reference frame) with the recorded time stamps. If it records nothing but a sequence of time stamps, then you'd know in advance of performing the experiment exactly what the record would show, and so what use would it be in that case? So, does this "record" include external events? and if so, which external events?

@SolomonSlow The atomic clock registers Caesium transition events and accumulates the running total on a counter. The value of the counter is continuously broadcast and can also be recorded by a non accelerating observer in parallel with the continuous value of his clock’s counter. Records from the recorded data set viewed side by side indicate that the counter on one clock starts to progressively lag behind the other at a point in the experiment.

@jamesfairclear, viewed side-by-side with what? Are you talking about records written by two independent clocks? If so, and assuming that the clocks are identical constructs, then the two records should be indistinguishable from one another, regardless of any relative motion between the clocks. If you want to compare something meaningful, then you need observers with a magic telescopes that allows each of them to read the other guy's clock. The record should show events like, "At the exact moment when my clock said X, I observed his clock saying Y."

@SolomonSlow "Are you talking about records written by two independent clocks? ". NO. The records from 2 independent clocks are recorded at the location of the clock that is not accelerated. Imagine yourself in a non accelerating spaceship with a clock whose readings are being continuously recorded and next to it a screen displaying the readings broadcast from another clock that is being accelerated. You will see that the readings from the accelerated clock are getting progressively behind the readings from your local clock and all without the need for a magic telescope! Is this now clear?

"...Is this now clear?" Start ing to clear up. In your most recent comment, the "record" is made by an observer who looks at two clocks,—one local, one remote—and who records their simultaneous readings. What you said earlier lead me to believe that each clock was supposed to be its own "observer," recording its own timestamps, and nothing else. You never actually said, "and nothing else," but I failed to infer any different meaning from your words. That was the source of my confusion. I agree that an observer will see a moving clock appear to tick at a different rate from their own.

@SolomonSlow "I agree that an observer will see a moving clock appear to tick at a different rate from their own". It doesn't just appear to be ticking at a different rate though. Less events are actually recorded by the clock subsequent to acceleration as substantiated by the broadcast data set and the recorded data set and agreed upon by all non accelerating observers. At a quantum level the quantity of transition events actually decreases as a consequence of acceleration. My interest is in the underlying physical causes of this effect.

No, you misunderstand what is happening. The difference in time is a consequence of the geometry of spacetime.
It might help to consider an analogy with 3d space. Suppose you drive your car in a straight line between points A and B, while I drive on a  meandering route. Your odometer will record a shorter trip than mine. Why is that? Is it because the acceleration I must undergo to follow a meandering route affects the workings of my odometer? No, of course not- my odometer records a longer trip because the actual distance along the meandering path is greater than the distance along a straight path.
Owing to its geometrical properties, in spacetime the effect is reversed. If you follow a straight path between two events while I follow a meandering one, your watch will record a longer time than mine. As with the odometer, it has nothing to do with the acceleration messing with the working of my watch- it is simply that the route through time is shorter on a meandering path than on the straight one. For instance, the temporal interval on a direct route between two events might be ten seconds, say, while on a meandering route it might be eight seconds. It is actually the lengths of the intervals that differ, and so any accurate clocks will measure them as differing.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

@EricSmith Spacetime is a convenient mathematical framework for predicting the path of an object within a gravitational field. The variable t is assigned a coordinate but that doesn't elevate time to a real physical structure intertwined with space. It might be but there is no observable evidence to substantiate such a notion. If you read Einstein's famous 1905 paper you will see that he makes no such claims about time. He treats time solely as a reading taken from a clock.

Your first mistake is here:  "The clock is accelerated and its tick rate is observed to decrease by all observers relative to the tick rates of their local clocks."
After a clock changes speed, it ticks slower than before in the frames of some observers and faster than before in the frames of others.

You misunderstand the scenario. The readings from the clock are continuously recorded in the frame of the accelerated clock. When any observer examines the readings after an experiment they will see that the readings indicate progressively less time being recorded. From this we deduce that the tick rate has decreased. The readings are a record of what actually happened and so a matter of fact.

@WillO is absolutely correct. The tick rate of the clocks relative to each other depend only on their relative speeds. Two clocks at rest relative to one another (aka moving at the same velocity, relative to another frame) tick at the same rate. You keep talking about "accelerated" clocks but this is a red herring. Acceleration has no direct effect on a clock's rate relative to some observer. It does have an indirect effect because the relative speeds are changing.  Speed is what matters. See e.g. Bailey et al in Nature 268 (1977)

@EricSmith "Acceleration has no direct effect on a clock's rate relative to some observer. It does have an indirect effect because the relative speeds are changing.".
I am not sure what point you are trying to make. Accelerating a clock affects its speed and thus affects its tick rate. The speed of a clock cannot change without it being accelerated. A record is kept of the accelerated clock's readings during the experiment which will indicate to any observer that its tick rate changed (increased or decreased) subsequent to the acceleration.

"A record is kept of the accelerated clock's readings during the experiment which will indicate to any observer that its tick rate changed (increased or decreased) subsequent to the acceleration."   How does perusing a record tell you anything about when it was recorded ?

@WillO "How does perusing a record tell you anything about when it was recorded ?".
The record illustrates that the clock recorded fewer events subsequent to being accelerated. That is the key point.

When does the recording of clock ticks stop? Think carefully about that . How do the observers know?

The physical properties like frequencies of atoms are of course valid in the proper time of the object.
One well known effect is the detection of muons. They are formed about twelve thousand meters in the atmosphere by cosmic rays, have a half-live of $2.2\mu$s and a relative velocity of $0.994$c. The time of falling in our frame (our coordinate time) is $$\Delta t = \frac{12*10^3}{0.994*3*10^8} \approx 40\mu s$$
In the muon proper time, the time interval is:$$\frac{40\mu s}{\gamma} = \frac{40}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{1-0.994^2}}} = \frac{40}{9.14} = 4.4\mu s$$
The expected fraction of muons detect on the Earth surface, considering time dilation is $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{4.4}{2.2}} = 0.25$$
The expected fraction of muons detect on the Earth surface, using coordinate time is $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{40}{2.2}} = 3*10^{-6}$$ almost none.
The number related to proper time is much closer to actual values. We concluded that the radioactive decay is valid, as expected, in the proper time of the particle.
Note that when we calculate $40 \mu s$ for the time of fall, we are implicitly placing a clock at twelve thousand meters and another one, synchronized with the first, at the surface. It would be also possible to suppose another frame, moving with respect to Earth and the muon, using 2 synchronized clocks at this frame, resulting in another coordinate time interval.
Finally, what is relevant is the relative velocity. But the acceleration has the effect of "freezing" a difference in time interval. For example, if the muon is suddenly decelerated when reaching the Earth surface, and becomes at rest in our frame, the clock at 12000 m is now synchronized with the clock on Earth surface also for the muon. And it realizes to have travelled to the future because both clocks show 35.6 s ahead of its own, keeping the difference as time passes.

Whether we focus on the extended life time of high speed Muons or accelerated clocks ticking at different rates the question remains as to the physical explanation.

The acceleration has the effect of making clear the trip to the future. I updated the answer.

"And it realizes to have travelled to the future because both clocks show 35.6 s ahead of its own, keeping the difference as time passes".
It is not possible to travel to the future. Clocks may differ but the muon is always in the present.

This had me confused:

The clock also continuously records its readings so that at the end of the experiment there is a single record upon which all observers will agree

IMO, That's an unnecessary complication.

...the continuous record of indicated times recorded by the clock during the experiment indicates that subsequent to the acceleration less events were recorded by the clock.

If all you're doing with the "record" is counting the number of recorded ticks between two events, then all you really are doing is asking how much time, according to the clock, elapsed between those two events. But if that's what you want to know, then you only need to record two things: What time was shown on the clock at the start, and what time was shown at the end.

So, let's say there are two, distinct spacetime events, which we will call "start" and "end." Let's say that they are causally related: The start event is in the past light cone of the end event, and the end event is in the future light cone of the start event. Finally, let's say that there are several "observers" who will see both events, and who will all agree that they are the same two events. Each observer is in motion relative to the others.

The clock is accelerated...

OK, sure. Every observer has a stopwatch (a.k.a., a "clock"), and if you wish, one of those observers (and their clock) can be accelerated.
Anyway, Each observer starts their clock when they see the start event, and they stop their clock when they see the end event. They then adjust the time shown by their clocks to account for the time it took for the light rays from the two events to reach them, and they record the duration of the spacetime interval between the two events.
All of the observers will agree that there is only one start event, only one end event, only one interval between the two events. They will not agree on the amount of time between the two events. This is not controversial, but does it mean that anybody's clock "ticked" faster or slower than anybody else's clock? No. It does not.
The correct interpretation is, that relative motion transforms their view of spacetime. The same spacetime interval represents a different displacement in space and a different span of time when it is seen in differently moving reference frames.
That's pretty much all there is to it, unless you want to dive into the math, which I am not prepared to do at this... um... time.

Addendum
You said, in a comment on my answer above,

[Special relativity] as written does not explain how acceleration causes an actual difference in the quantities of events [e.g., clock ticks] occurring.

James Clerk Maxwell upended the world of physics when he published "A Dynamical Theory of the Electromagnetic Field]" in 1865. Physicists struggled for decades afterward to reconcile Maxwell's equations with the rest of known physical law until Albert Einstein pulled all of their loose ends together in the Theory of Relativity.
Einstein's theory contains rigorous, mathematical proof that if the Principle of Relativity is valid,*  and if Maxwell's equations are valid,† then observers in differently moving frames of reference, looking at the same two spacetime events, will disagree on how much time elapsed between the two events. What's even more weird! If the two events are not causally connected, then two observers will not necessarily even agree on the order in which the two events happened.‡
Relativity does not merely explain how different clocks measure different spans of time between the same two events. Relativity predicted it. Relativity is where the idea came from in the first place.
If you want to understand more, I strongly urge you to watch the whole sequence of MinutePhysics videos on special relativity. By the time you get to chapter 8, "The Twins Paradox," I hope you will be convinced. (Don't worry, the "chapters" are only around three minutes each.)

* The earliest version of the Principle of Relativity was described by Galileo in 1632, and it has guided physicists ever since.
† Pretty much our entire modern understanding of the classical behavior of electricity, magnetism, and electromagnetic radiation can be derived from Maxwell's equations.
‡The answer to the famous barn and pole paradox depends on the fact that an observer who is standing on the ground and an observer who is riding on the pole will not agree upon the order in which certain important events occur (e.g., doors opening, doors closing, pole ends entering and leaving the barn)

“They will not agree on the amount of time between the two events.” The key point is that all observers will agree from both the broadcast data set that the accelerated clock records progressively fewer events as a consequence of acceleration. This is compelling evidence that acceleration affects the tick rate of clocks. We can arbitrarily characterise n events as m seconds of time but as clocks evidentially tick at different rates this holds no useful meaning unless it turns out that time is a real physical medium flowing at different rates and affecting the progress of clocks.

@jamesfairclear, We agree that different clocks can count a different number of ticks between observations of two events, but we disagree on the reason why. I'm just repeating what the theory of relativity says. That's the same theory that predicted the phenomenon before anybody ever thought to look for it. The same theory that has withstood a century of scrutiny and experimentation. You keep saying that it's wrong, but you haven't said why it is wrong and your idea is right. IMO, you're going to have to come up with a more compelling argument if you want to be taken seriously.

"We agree that different clocks can count a different number of ticks between observations of two events, but we disagree on the reason why".
It seems to me that we have not yet established a reason on which we might disagree. Unless your view is that time is a real physical medium flowing at different rates and affecting the progress of clocks. I am not claiming that SR is incorrect and certainly there is good agreement between predictions and observations. However SR as written does not explain how acceleration causes an actual difference in the  quantities of events occurring.

@jamesfairclear, See the "Addendum" to my answer, above.

The simultaneity of relativity illustrates that different observers will not agree on whether 2 events are simultaneous where light signals have a longer path to 1 observer than the other. This doesn't explain though why a clock records a different quantity of events as a consequence of being accelerated.

@jamesfairclear, If you and I cannot agree on whether two events are simultaneous, then that implies that we do not agree on how much time has elapsed between them: One of us thinks it's zero time, and the other of us thinks it's some non-zero amount of time. And, how did either of us judge the amount of time if not by using a "clock?" [Hint: For purpose of discussing relativity, a clock is any process that evolves over time, and that includes processes that happen inside your own brain.]

A light sensor on the middle of the platform correctly detects the lightning strikes at each end of the moving train to be simultaneous because the light signals from each travel the same distance to it. A light sensor in the middle of the train correctly detects that the front strike occurs first because the light signal has a shorter distance to travel to it. This is exactly what is expected without the need for clocks. It is solely the order of events at a given location that is detected.

@jamesfairclear, It looks to me as if you just asserted that the distance between the front of a train and its middle is less than the distance from the back of the train to its middle. Is this some definition of "middle" that I don't know about? If not, then can you help me to better understand what you are saying?

@jamesfairclear, Forget the train for a moment. Let's add sensor F, which is attached to the platform close to the front lightning strike, and let's call the one in the middle of the platform M. You said that sensor M "correctly detects the lightning strikes at each end...to be simultaneous because the light signals from each travel the same distance to it." Does your argument also mean that sensor F "correctly detects that the front strike occurs first because the light signal has a shorter distance to travel to it?" If so, how does it make any sense? If not, then what am I not understanding?

P.S., In any discussion about the theory of relativity, it is implicitly understood (if not explicitly stated) that when we talk about the time when somebody observed an event, we are talking about the time, in the observer's reference frame, at the location of the event. If the observer sees the event from a distance, then we assume that the observer has accounted for the time needed for the signal from the event to reach themselves. The timestamp assigned to the event itself should not depend on whether the signal was sent by light, or by sound, or by a sticky note on the back of a turtle.

2 bolts of lightning strike simultaneously at both ends of a moving train with both ends of the train simultaneously at both ends of the platform. light signals from the strike at the front of the train have less distance to travel to the sensor in the middle of the train as the sensor is moving towards the light source.  There is no need for any further sensors or measurements by clocks. The platform sensor indicates that the lightning strikes are simultaneous whereas the train sensor indicates that the front strike was first. Both sensors are correct. Is that clearer?

@jamesfairclear, What is clear to me is that you effectively are saying that the theory of relativity—which has been firmly established, for more than a century now—is wrong. You expect to be taken seriously despite the fact that you never say why you think it's wrong, or why you think your own idea is right. You just keep saying over, and over again how you think the universe works.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLlv_aZjHXc&t=78s You're channeling John Cleese, I'm channeling Michael Palin. Share and enjoy!

that is one of my favourite sketches of all time but I can assure you that I am not arguing in my spare time! I am not saying that SR is wrong but I am interested in what physically causes a clock to accumulate different quantities of events after being accelerated. This doesn't seem to follow from the simultaneity of relativity which says that different non accelerating observers will disagree on the order of 2 events. As acceleration causes a clock to move at a different speed through space we might conclude the quantity of events is governed by the distance between events.
